# Have two questions regarding Godel numbering about natural numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity, computability

I want to mention first that these are homework questions. I have done 3 out of 4.

"Do you remember how we used the pairing function and the Gödel numbering to associate each program in the language L with a unique natural number? To be precise, we demanded that every program in L is associated with unique number, and we also required that every natural number is associated with a valid program in L . Now it is your task to develop such one-to-one mappings for other things. If you think that a mapping cannot be defined, please give a reason."

1. Define such a mapping for quintuples of natural numbers.

This one was pretty easy.

```
(a, b, c, d, e) ↔ < <a, b>, <c, <d, e> > > (one possible solution)
```

2. Define such a mapping for odd natural numbers.

I am not sure about this one. I was able to figure out the even number one using the example of where f(x) = (x/2)

```
(x1, x2, ..., xn, xn+1, xn+2, ..., xn+m) ↔ [m, f(x1), f(x2), ..., f(xn)] – 1 with f(x) = ⎣x/2⎦
```

3. Define such a mapping for pairs (x, y), where x and y are letters from the English alphabet.

   I determined this is not possible because there are only a finite number of such pairs.
4. Define such a mapping for the set of natural numbers {0, 1,…, 1000}.

   I determined this is not possible because there are only a finite number of such pairs as well.

I just wanted to confirm if my thinking was correct in these questions. 2 gave me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little unclear; I'm confused whether they're asking for (e.g.)

- An injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^5$,
- An injection from $\mathbb{N}^5$ to $\mathbb{N}$, or
- A bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^5$.

The choice of interpretation here determines whether 3 and 4 are doable, as you observe.

Meanwhile, I don't understand your approach to 2: what is the thing you've written down? What two sets is it a map between? The way I read the question, they're asking for a bijection between the naturals and the odd naturals, which looks nothing like what you've written.

Comment: so i believe the question is referring to what we did in class.

Comment: ^Ignore that, i cant edit it. In class, we were pairing functions and godel numbers using this equation, <x, y> + 1 = 2^x(2y + 1).  I am not sure what you are referring to with injection and bijections. We did not use those terms at all.